# Highlight previous bullet in navigation bar for beamer frame

Tags: beamer, numbering, mini-frames

I'm also using a theme which displays bullet in the navigation bar, each corresponding to a slide, and fills the bullet point corresponding to the current slide. Certain slides in my presentation are very short, because they are the continuation of the previous slide, and I would therefore like them not to contribute an extra bullet point. For example, in

```
\begin{frame}{Some frame}
This is a frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some frame II}
This is frame is short, and is meant to conclude the topic of the previous one
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A new frame}
Here I'm discussing something new
\end{frame}
```

I would like that when currently viewing `Some frame II` the bullet point that is highlighted in the navigation bar that is the same as for `Some frame`, and in `A new frame` the next bullet point is highlighted.

This is what happens when you use `\framebreak`, but I don't want to use this because I also want to pause the frame in several places (and also want to manually control where I split the frame). I've found ways to get no new bullet point for some frame, but not to keep the one from the previous frame highlighted.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\title[title]{title}

\author[author]{author\inst{1}}

\institute[institution] % (optional)
{
  \inst{1}%
institution
}

\date[date] % (optional)
{date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This talk}
  \tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Some frame}
  This is a frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some frame II}
  This is frame is short, and is meant to conclude the topic of the previous one
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A new frame}
  Here I'm discussing something new
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Some frame}
  This is a frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A new frame}
  Here I'm discussing something new
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal example that replicates your current behaviour? You code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and include the theme you're using. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner thank you for your comment. I've edited my answer with a MWE.

Comment: That amount of code was no necessary. I've trimmed it down considerably, but could also remove the title frame (since that doesn't add anything), the ToC as well as the footer definition. The only thing of essential use in the MWE is the theme and the frames, as depicted [here](https://pastebin.com/TvpNdj7i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the `\only<slides>` overlay specification in the following way:

```
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Some frame}
  % Use a single frame => no frame counter stepping/bullet change
  \only<1-3>{%
    This is a frame% Slide 1
    %
    \pause
    
    Here is some more stuff - beautiful stuff!% Slide 2
    
    \pause
    
    \includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}% Slide 3
  }
  \only<4>{%
    % Slide 4
    This is frame is short, and is meant to conclude the topic of the previous one
  }
\end{frame}
```

Since your content is contained within the same `frame`, there's no stepping of the navigation counter/bullet. You use `\only` to remove invalid entries from the frame completely, with `\pause` to step through content that should result in multiple slides.

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks. I hadn't thought of using `\only` to sneak everything in a single frame.